# PHP Array_Diff and Array of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a simple PHP page reporting results from various sensors. Since the number of sensors and their locations will vary I need to account for that in my code.

```
$Location_Array = array('Sanding', 'Outside');

foreach($Location_Array as $Locations) {

${"Time_Array_" . $Locations} = array();//Array data fed via array_push via mysql query- clipped 

}

$diff = array_diff(${"Time_Array_" . $Location_Array[0]}, ${"Time_Array_" . $Location_Array[1]});//This is the problem line - It does work
```

As you can see my Time_Array_LOCATION is an array that is created via an array of locations. The locations will be set by the end user via a settings file. The code does work but each location would have to be manually put into array_diff. The sensors report at specific times and if one fails to report all of the arrays will have that key/value removed. I need to have it compare all of the arrays dynamically from the Location_Array.

Like:

```
$diff = array_diff($Time_Array_Sanding, $Time_Array_Outside, $Time_Array_ANOTHER);
```

I figure it is something simple and I am just overlooking it. I thought of looping it but that returns the values not the array variable name etc...
I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance for the help.

additional info:

The arrays are nothing more than MySQL time stamps. The times just have to match. The data is (09-20-2016 9:00, 09-20-2016 9:30) and so on. If one doesn't have the 9:00 time stamp. I drop the data for that time on all of the arrays.

```
$date = $row["date_time"];
$dt = substr($date, 5, 11);
array_push(${"Time_Array_" . $Locations}, $dt);
```

Comment: Can you give a working example *with* data in the individual arrays, sowe can run the code and see some data produced in `$diff`? And then specify which outcome you you desire?

Comment: As you want to drop things which don't occur in all arrays, shouldn't you use `array_intersect` instead of `array_diff`?

Comment: Array_intersect is an option but I was using the difference in other parts of the program. But still the problem would exist of how to put the array arguments in as the dynamic list/array of locations which is what I can't get past. I had thoughts of how you can pass an array to a function like: function takes_array ($array). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to store your data in one super-array, instead of distinct variables. It will allow you to pass all arrays to standard PHP functions via [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$Time_Arrays = []; // Will be a 2D array -- the "super-array".

// You would fill up this data structure from the database, with something like:
/*
while ($row = $pdo->fetch()) {
    // Assuming there is:
    // - a column "type" which can have values "Sanding", "Outside", ...
    // - a column "time_stamp" which has the date/time value to store:
    $Time_Arrays[$row["type"]][] = $row['time_stamp'];
}
*/

// Since I don't have the database, here are some sample data.
// Note that only 2 date/time values are common to all:
$Time_Arrays["Sanding"] = ['09-20-2016 9:00', '09-20-2016 9:30', '09-20-2016 10:00', '09-20-2016 10:30'];
$Time_Arrays["Outside"] = ['09-20-2016 9:00', '09-20-2016 9:30', '09-20-2016 13:00', '09-20-2016 10:30'];
$Time_Arrays["Another"] = ['09-20-2016 9:00', '09-20-2016 11:30', '09-20-2016 10:00', '09-20-2016 10:30'];

// The trick with `call_user_func_array`: merge all sub-arrays together into one array,
// and then remove duplicates from it:
$merged = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $Time_Arrays));

// Same trick to get intersection (only values that occur in all sub-arrays):
$intersected = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $Time_Arrays);

// Finally get the overall difference (values that do not occur in all sub-arrays):
$diff = array_diff($merged, $intersected);

// Show the results
echo "Merged (all values):\n";
print_r($merged);
echo "Intersected (common values only):\n";
print_r($intersected);
echo "Diff (non-common values only):\n";
print_r($diff);
```

Output of this script is:

```
Merged (all values):
Array
(
    [0] => 09-20-2016 9:00
    [1] => 09-20-2016 9:30
    [2] => 09-20-2016 10:00
    [3] => 09-20-2016 10:30
    [6] => 09-20-2016 13:00
    [9] => 09-20-2016 11:30
)
Intersected (common values only):
Array
(
    [0] => 09-20-2016 9:00
    [3] => 09-20-2016 10:30
)
Diff (non-common values only):
Array
(
    [1] => 09-20-2016 9:30
    [2] => 09-20-2016 10:00
    [6] => 09-20-2016 13:00
    [9] => 09-20-2016 11:30
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/645813).

#### Note

Once you get how `call_user_func_array` works, it would be tempting to do this as a short-cut:

```
$diff = call_user_func_array('array_diff', $Time_Arrays);
```

But that will not give the desired result, as it only returns the values from the *first* sub-array that are not in any of the others, while you would also need the values that are not in the *first* but do occur in one of the other sub-arrays. The above code overcomes this by first getting the merge of all sub-arrays.

Comment: That will work out. Few minor changes to fit into my program but all is well. Thanks for your help.